# Joining on null values only if no other results

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

| Table A | Table B |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Column A | Column A | Column B |
| A | A | 1 |
| B | A |  |
| C | B | 2 |
|  | C |  |

Table A and Table B both have Column A. Table B has Column B. The Column A's in Table B have multiple rows for multiple values of Column B. How do I return a result like the below table? Any join that I've tried results in multiple rows for the A value because the table that I'm joining has multiple results. I'd like it to show a result in Column B only if there is a result from Table B and to include null values only if there are no other values.

| Results Table |  |
| --- | --- |
| Column A | Column B |
| A | 1 |
| B | 2 |
| C |  |

Comment: Oracle SQL Developer is a client application used to access databases; it is not a database. Please [edit] the question and tag the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous ways you can tackle this. You haven't revealed your specific RDBMS but the following correlated sub-query is one way.

```
select colA, (
  select colB 
  from TableB b 
  where b.colA = a.colA 
  order by v.colB desc 
  limit 1
)
from TableA a;
```

You may need to use *top* or *offset / fetch* instead of *limit*, depending on your RDBMS.

Comment: Is this not just a wordy way of saying `MAX()`?

Answer (score 0):

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE table_a (
  `Col_A` VARCHAR(1)
);

INSERT INTO table_a
  (`Col_A`)
VALUES
  ('A'),
  ('B'),
  ('C'),
  ('C');

CREATE TABLE table_b (
  `Col_A` VARCHAR(1),
  `Col_B` INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO table_b
  (`Col_A`, `Col_B`)
VALUES
  ('A', '1'),
  ('A', NULL),
  ('B', '2');
```

---

**Query**

```
SELECT Col_A, MAX(Col_B) Col_B
FROM table_a
LEFT JOIN table_b USING(Col_A)
GROUP BY Col_A;
```

| Col_A | Col_B |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 2 |
| C |  |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/j29rUZNTmXjFAS58N1Xh2V/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT column_a,
       column_b
FROM   (
  SELECT a.column_a,
         b.column_b,
         RANK() OVER (
           PARTITION BY a.column_a
           ORDER BY CASE WHEN b.column_b IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
         ) AS rnk
  FROM   table_a a
         INNER JOIN table_b b
         ON (a.column_a = b.column_a)
)
WHERE  rnk = 1;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_a (column_a) AS
SELECT 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE table_b (column_a, column_b) AS
SELECT 'A', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', NULL FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | COLUMN_A | COLUMN_B |
> | --- | --- |
> | A | 1 |
> | B | 2 |
> | C | *null* |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=82d6cc64bcb4337f2593570f0be8ebac)*